# building a list of ints in ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml, int

I want to write a function that does builds a list between two ints, inclusive

rec myFunc x y would build a list with all the ints between x and y, including x and y

For the logic right now I have something like this:

```
let rec buildList i n = let x = i+1 in if i <= n then i::(buildList x n)
```

But this gives me an error "Expression has type 'a list but but an expression was expected of type unit.

I thought buildList is returning a list of ints, and i as an int, so the cons operator would be valid, but its saying it should be void?

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the condition is true, you return the list `i::(buildList x n)`. If it's not true, what do you return ?

Add `else []` to your function to return the empty list when the condition is not met.
When you don't have any `else`, the compiler supposes it is `else ()` (hence the error message).

Comment: Wow, I totally overlooked that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` is missing an `else` condition

I suggest that you use a tail recursive function:

```
let buildList x y =
  let (x,y) = if x<y then (x,y) else (y,x) in
  let rec aux cpt acc =
      if cpt < x then acc
      else aux (cpt-1) (cpt::acc)
  in aux y []
```

First, make sure that you ordered your boundaries correctly (idiot-proof), and then construct the list thank to a local recursive function which takes an accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Two alternatives relying on batteries' package,

Using unfold,  which purpose is to build list,

```
let range ~from:f ~until:u = 
    BatList.unfold f (function | n when n <= u -> Some (n, succ n) | _ -> None)
```

Using Enum, allowing to work with lazy datastructure,

```
# BatList.of_enum @@ BatEnum.(1--9);;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8; 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, this respects the ordering of the arguments.

```
let rec iota n m = 
  let oper = if n < m then succ else pred  in 
    if n = m then [n] else n :: iota (oper n) m
```

**Edit:**

The operator selection is inside the recursive part, it should better be outside like this:

```
let iota n m = 
  let oper = if n < m then succ else pred  in 
    let rec f1 n m = if n = m then [n] else n :: f1 (oper n) m in
      f1 n m
```

At more than 200000 elements I get a stack overflow (so here we are)

```
# iota 0 250000;;
Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?).
```

Todo: tail recursion

Answer (score 0):

```
let buildList i n =
 let rec aux acc i =
   if i <= n then
     aux (i::acc) (i+1)
   else (List.rev acc)
 in
 aux [] i
```

Test:

```
# buildList 1 3;;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
# buildList 2 1;;
- : int list = []
# buildList 0 250000;;
- : int list =
[0; 1; 2; 3; .... 296; 297; 298; ...]
```